# Apex - Divided a page into equal height squares

Tags: grid, flexbox, oracle-apex

I have a page where I want to place 4 reports so the get equal height and width and of course is fully responsive.

report#1, report#2

report#3, report#4

I am using Apex 5.0 and as I see it I have to use the grid. So I have placed all 4 reports in the same row and column with a cold-span of 12.
I am trying to use flexbox but having trouble setting the outer element.

Is there a way to get the same result using Apex's build in grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this it quite simple.

If you want the regions to display 2 per row on a desktop like your example:

> report#1, report#2
>
> report#3, report#4

then set the column span to 6 on them all (so that they occupy 6/12 grid columns = 1/2 page width), and set the Start New Row property to Yes on 1 &3, No on 2 & 4.  It will look like this when run on the desktop:

[image]

When run on a small device, the layout will change to show each region at full width on a new row:

[image]

You can see this for yourself here on [this demo on apex.oracle.com](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=20820:3)